# Xububtu 12.04 Internet super slow on wireless but fast on wired

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, xubuntu, internet

When connected to the internet via wireless it runs really slow, for example, when I’m logged in to my Google drive account and try to access a folder it takes super long to load and that's if it does. It sometimes does it in other websites, But when I connect my laptop to my router via wired connection it runs fine and all folders on my Google drive account open up smoothly. Could it be a driver issue. I install Xubuntu 12.04 on my laptop Windows XP. I'm really starting to like Xubuntu and I want to keep enjoying it.

Answer (score 1):

Might be the 802.11n driver issue, happened to me too (regular ubuntu). Try this:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

if that did the trick you can make the change permanent as shown [here](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) by running:

```
sudo su
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-disable11n.conf
```

then you should still have working wifi after a restart

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Good post! You included details, formatted the answer very well, and referenced a link the right way (including a snippet/quote from the link). Keep up posting like this and you should become recognized here!

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install your broadcom driver. here is a link if you want.

http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/install-broadcom-sta-b43-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-11-04/

Good Luck, and best regards!